# Issue with Sum over Ordered Window in pyspark in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, sum, window, sql-order-by

**EDIT:
I got this figured out. I had been reading the documentation poorly as the default frame for ordered window is a rangeFrame and not a rowFrame.**

First of all I want to thank this community for the great questions and answers. I have been learning pyspark for only few months now and I have found this site really helpful.

I am using spark 2.4.5 in Databricks.

According to the documentation when using Window with OrderBy the frame should be by default unboundedPreceding, currentRow.
How ever this doesn't seem to be the case or these is something else wrong.
When I explicitly define the frame I get different results than when I rely on the default.

Here is an example code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.window as W
df = spark.range(0, 1000)
#partitionBy and orderBy columns
for k in ['a','e']:
  df=df.withColumn(k, (F.rand()*10).cast('int'))
#column for the sum, 0's and 1's
df=df.withColumn('o', (F.round(F.pow(F.rand(),10)) ).cast('int'))
#two ways to count the sum
w=W.Window.partitionBy('a').orderBy('e').rowsBetween(W.Window.unboundedPreceding, W.Window.currentRow)      
df = df.withColumn('sum', F.sum('o').over(w))

w2=W.Window.partitionBy('a').orderBy('e')      
df = df.withColumn('sum2', F.sum('o').over(w2))

display(df.orderBy('a','e', 'sum'))
```

If you compare the sum and sum2 values you notice that they are not always the same.
So my question is: is this really a bug or have I misunderstood something or is there for example different defaults for this in Databricks

Comment: You have duplicate values in `e`, which introduces ambiguity in the window order by definition

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think the reason is ambiguity but I found out the real reason after further investigating. I had been reading the documentation poorly as the default frame is rangeFrame and not a rowFrame.